# ngx-color-picker dialog box closes after clicking outside

Tags: javascript, angular

I have used ngx-color-picker in our project. but the issue I am getting is, whenever I click outside of a dialog, it closes. I don't want to close the dialog if it is clicked outside of the dialog. Is there any inbuilt event in ngx-color-picker which takes care of this situation?

I used this package:
    https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-color-picker

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [function from the source](https://github.com/zefoy/ngx-color-picker/blob/master/src/lib/color-picker.component.ts#L300)

```
 public onMouseDown(event: MouseEvent): void {
    if (!this.isIE10 && this.cpDialogDisplay === 'popup' &&
        event.target !== this.directiveElementRef.nativeElement &&
        !this.isDescendant(this.elRef.nativeElement, event.target) &&
        !this.isDescendant(this.directiveElementRef.nativeElement, event.target) &&
        this.cpIgnoredElements.filter((item: any) => item === event.target).length === 0)
    {
      if (!this.cpSaveClickOutside) {
        this.setColorFromString(this.initialColor, false);

        this.directiveInstance.colorChanged(this.initialColor);
      }

      this.closeColorPicker();
    }
  }
```

You would have to use:

```
cpDialogDisplay = 'inline'
```

Instead of

```
cpDialogDisplay = 'popup'
```

In order to prevent this behaviour, however **this will disable the dialog**.

So, the answer to your question:

> I don't want to close the dialog if it is clicked outside of the
>   dialog. Is there any inbuilt event in ngx-color-picker which takes
>   care of this situation?

Is **No**.

The way I see it, as with any open-source project, you have a few options:

1) Change the source code of the component, submit your changes to the project in github and, provided the maintainers agree with your implementation, your new feature will be a part of future releases of said component;

2) You build your own component from scratch, maybe heavily based from the current [ngx-color-picker](https://github.com/zefoy/ngx-color-picker), with the feature you want, and maybe others.

3) Look for other similar projects/components that may have the feature/behavior you're looking for.

Comment: 'inline' will stop toggle. How to make both working.

Comment: @loneWolf Although probably not the answer you wanted, I have updated it.

Answer (score 0):

From [docs](https://github.com/zefoy/ngx-color-picker), there is no such input...
Maybe you can have a look to `inline` positioning instead of `popup`.

```
[cpDialogDisplay]            // Dialog positioning mode: 'popup', 'inline' ('popup').
                             //   popup: dialog is shown as popup (fixed positioning).
                             //   inline: dialog is shown permanently (static positioning).
```

You can still fork the project if you really need this feature.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't `cpCloseClickOutside` do the job?

```
[cpCloseClickOutside]        // Close the color picker dialog when user clicks outside (true).
```